# sql deleting matches from an excel lookup

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to write an SQL query that will delete up to 500 matches from an Excel sheet that has been saved as a csv and imported.
The database is for a WordPress site. Is there a way to not have to enter all 500 matches directly into the SQL query? The matches and the exact number of matches will change each time this is used.

Background Wordpress products  are imported and updated from a supplier scrape but this doesn't deal with discontinued products, so finding them by running a lookup/match in Excel but then a little awkward to paste them into a query each time.

Comment: MySQL can load a CVS [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) into a table which you can compare? Then it's just as simple as writing a `JOIN` query or using `IN()` operator to delete, insert or update the WordPress tables.

Comment: i advice you this read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) if you need help and provide the WordPress table with `SHOW CREATE TABLE table`,  example data (CVS data and some WordPress table records) and also post expected results

Comment: Thanks will work on providing a MCVE. In the meantime I almost have this using a different approach:

Comment: THX working on providing a MCVE. It looks like I need to  eliminate the VLOOKUPS in Excel as the titles  contain () and ""
I  imported a csv into the db which creates a copy of the current products column
Then I copied it to the wp_posts table with
ALTER TABLE wp_posts 
ADD COLUMN titles_current TEXT FIRST;
and

INSERT INTO wp_posts (titles_current)
SELECT `titles_current`
FROM TABLE_2;

Now need to delete the entries in wp_posts where the post_titles do not have a match in the titles_current column
Below doesn't work:

DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title NOT IN titles_current;

Comment: solved it by refrencing TABLE_2 instead:DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_title NOT IN (SELECT titles_current FROM TABLE_2)